# Mailjet Campaign API : How to set a unique CustomName value?

Tags: mailjet

I want to set a unique alphanumeric name to my campaign to retrieve it later from that name.

I use to set Headers => 'X-Mailjet-Campaign' but now i am using the API and can't make it work.

And API doc doesn't help at all cause there is no exemple given.

Does anyone know how i can set this CustomName value ?

I tried CampaignID And CampaignALT during my post on "CampaignDraft/Create" but none is working (it tells me this is not integer).

Answer (score 0):

I lead the API at Mailjet.

I assume you're referring to our Send API as documented [here](https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#send-transactional-email). As you'll find here, I believe you're looking for the `Mj-campaign` property in the JSON payload. The full reference of fields is available at https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#send-api-json-properties.

Since I do not know which programming language you're using, I won't be able to give you a valid sample code but I think the doc should contain all you need to move forward.

Let me know.

Comment: Ok but i need to send my message to one of your contact list. As i understand i must use the "Campaign" API ? Does "Mj-campaign" apply to the "CampaignDraft ->create" method ? If not how can i prevent creating a campaignDraft twice for the same content / contactList ?

Comment: Then I misunderstood your need, sorry. My colleague Zhivko just told me you're in touch with him already and he just got back to you. I recommend we pursue here since things are already on-going. Once solved, I'll make sure to post the right answer here for future reference. Thanks for having chosen Mailjet to power your emails!